# One Side of Bones Controls Both

Tags: rigging, bones

[image]I've been rigging this guy for a while while following a tutorial, and after i did automatic weights the right side controls the left side and the left side controls nothing. I need to know how to fix this! (first experience with blender and 3d modelling)

Comment: Please add some details to help us figure out what's happening.  Screenshots might help, uploading your blend file might be even better.  But to take a stab in the dark, were you perhaps using a mirror modifier that you failed to apply before parenting the mesh to the armature?

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: Well if that is your weight paint for that bone, there's the problem!  You only want that weight paint to be affecting the vertices for the one leg (i.e. the mesh should only be non-blue on the leg where the bone is located).  I'm not sure why automatic weights did not work for you, You can either fix it manually in weight paint or (probably better) try to get to the bottom of why the automatic weights didn't work properly.  Again, were you using a mirror modifier on the mesh?  Was it applied before parenting?

Comment: How do you delete the weight on one side

Comment: In weight painting, you can literally just paint the side you don't want blue.  That will give those vertices a weight of zero, which means the bone won't affect them.